# usermod -a -G group user not adding user to group but no error is seen

Tags: linux, permissions, usergroups

I need for a user2 to access user1 directory and files to run a program in user2 that cannot be ran by different users successfully. So I want to add user1 to the group user2 belongs to. I tried as root

```
usermod -a -G group user1
```

but its not adding user1 to group but no error is seen

groups user1 tells me it is in the group but none of the directories change to group

specifically I want access to a directory owned by user1 on a mounted drive